# What should I do about Python 2.7.9 not looking for SSL certificates in the right place on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, python, ssl

I have a FreeBSD 10.0 system, and a couple of days ago, I upgraded my `python27` port from Python 2.7.8 to Python 2.7.9, which enabled SSL verification by default.  Unsurprisingly, it broke my existing Python scripts that connected to servers with self-signed certificates.  Surprisingly, it broke my scripts that connected to servers with valid SSL certificates.

I have `/usr/local/etc/ssl/cert.pem` (which is a symlink to `/usr/local/share/certs/ca-root-nss.crt`) but not `/etc/ssl/cert.pem`.  My Python installation expects the latter:

```
>>> ssl.get_default_verify_paths()
DefaultVerifyPaths(cafile=None,
                   capath=None,
                   openssl_cafile_env='SSL_CERT_FILE',
                   openssl_cafile='/etc/ssl/cert.pem',
                   openssl_capath_env='SSL_CERT_DIR',
                   openssl_capath='/etc/ssl/certs')
```

I've worked around this by creating an appropriate symlink, but is there a better approach?  Should this be necessary, or is this something that should have been addressed by the port itself?

(And I could set `SSL_CERT_FILE` in my environment too, but I'd rather not have to do that all the time.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The respective FreeBSD bug is [here](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=196431). The fix adds symlinks:

```
ln -sf /usr/local/etc/ssl/cert.pem /etc/ssl/cert.pem
ln -sf /usr/local/etc/ssl/cert.pem /usr/local/openssl/cert.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

I had `ca_root_nss` which provides `/usr/local/etc/ssl/cert.pem` but not `/etc/ssl/cert.pem` needed by python 2.7.9. So I ended up linking the second one to the first one.
I could not find any reference to this bug on https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/.